# What does 330 followed by 64GPH d on a tantalum capacitor mean?

Tags: capacitor, identification, tantalum

What do these numbers mean? I need to buy one, but with the following codes on it I cannot find anything.

[image: photo of tantal capacitor]

Comment: That tantalum doesn't look bad... these usually burn horribly when they fail.  Are you sure this is the problem?

Comment: For tantalum caps the 330 usually means 330 µF (ceramic it would usually mean 330 pF).  The other numbers/letters are unique to the manufacturer.  What is this on?

Comment: Gallons Per Hour?

Comment: @rdtsc it's broken physically by accident. Now I search for a new one and I see 2V option and 6V options. How to know which Voltage to choose? It's for HP EliteBook 820.

Comment: Could try to power it up and read what DC voltage is on it.  Then double that number at least, and that should be the replacement's voltage rating.

Comment: @rdtsc Can I just blindly purchase a 6V or even bigger (if it's even possible) option?

Comment: Could try that, but if it is too low, it risks of fire and irreparable damage.